# nested queries in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Here is my sql, i am struggling to translate this to laravel 5.8 query builder syntax.

```
    SELECT CC AS CountOfVisits, Count(CC) AS Users
    FROM
        (
        SELECT user_id, count(user_id) AS CC FROM mytable
        GROUP BY user_id
        ) AS CC
    GROUP BY CC;
```

I tried this:

```
     $frequency= DB::connection('mysql2')
            ->select(DB::raw('CC AS CountOfVisits'), DB::raw('Count(CC) AS Users'))
            ->from(function($sq)
            {
               $sq->select(DB::raw('user_id, count(user_id) AS CC FROM '))
                    ->from('mytable')
                    ->groupBy('user_id');
            })
            ->groupBy('CC')
            ->get();
```

it errors with

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings()
>   must be of the type array, object given, called in
>   /var/app/portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
>   on line 665

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: can you remove FROM from this query user_id, count(user_id) AS CC FROM

Comment: i think you first need to check your sql query and please use different names and columns in the subquery so that it is clearly understood what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: You're gettnig that error because the `Db::connection()->select()` method expects the FULL query as per: `DB::connection()->select('select * from users')`. The secont parameter handles any bindings for that query's where clause operators. I'm trying to find the correct handler for you but hope this helps a bit in the mean time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is that the returned connection is expecting string for the full query with additional bindings on the second parameter. You can still build it using illuminate's query builder first if you like, then run the select using the generated string.

```php
$query = DB::query()
    ->select('CC AS CountOfVisits', DB::raw('count(CC) AS Users'))
    ->fromSub(function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query) {
        $query->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(user_id) AS CC '))
            ->from('mytable')
            ->groupBy('user_id');
    }, 'CC')
    ->groupBy('CC');

$result = DB::connection()->select($query->toSql());
```

Comment: Thanks Jon this worked! I am pretty new to laravel and still learning heaps.